# Display confusion matrix when called from a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

I have a function that imports a random forest classifier from scikit learn, i fit it with data and finally I want to display accuracy, kappa and confusion matrix. All works except printing the confusion matrix. I do not get any error, but the confusion matrix does not print.

I have tried calling `print(cm)` and it works, but it does not print in usual pandas dataframe style, which is what I am looking for.

Here's the code

```
def rf_clf(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42):
    """This function splits the data into train and test and fits it in a random forest classifier 
    to the data provided, analysing its errors (Accuracy and Kappa). Also as this is classification,
    the function will output a confusion matrix"""

    #Split data in train and test, as well as predictors (X) and targets, (y)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, random_state=random_state, stratify=y)

    #import random forest classifier
    base_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=random_state)

    #Train the model
    base_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

    #make predictions on test set
    y_pred=base_model.predict(X_test)

    #Print Accuracy and Kappa
    print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
    print("Kappa:",metrics.cohen_kappa_score(y_test, y_pred))

    #create confusion matrix
    labs = [y_test[i][0] for i in range(len(y_test))]
    cm = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(labs, y_pred))
    cm #here is the issue. Kinda works with print(cm)
```

Comment: Do you want the column names and indexes? Perhaps try feeding while creating the dataframe itself?
ex. pd.DataFrame( ... , columns = [ ... ], index = [ ... ])

Comment: try `return cm` in last line

Comment: Thanks @ChrisA, your answer works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Import metrics from sklearn at the beginning.

   ```
   from sklearn import metrics
   ```
2. Use this when you want to show confussion matrix.

   ```
   # Get and show confussion matrix
   cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
   print(cm)
   ```

With this you should view confussion matrix in raw text.

If you want to show confussion Matrix with colours do it in this other way:

1. Import

   ```
   from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
   import pandas as pd
   import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
   ```
2. Use it that way:

   ```
   cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
   cmat_df = pd.DataFrame(cm, index=class_names, columns=class_names)
   ax = sns.heatmap(cmat_df, square=True, annot=True, cbar=False)
   ax.set_xlabel('Predicción')
   ax.set_ylabel('Real')`
   ```
3. Hope for the best!